# Display multiple UserControls with the same name in the Visual Studio WinForms designer toolbox

Tags: visual-studio, winforms, designer

In my WinForms project I have multiple `UserControl`-s with the same name ("View"), in diferent namespaces.

If I understand well, the designer hides the controls with the same name as the designed control from the toolbox. So when I'm in design mode on one of the "View"-s I don't see the other ones.

Is there a way to change the name displayed in the toolbox for an `UserControl` ? I have tried using `DisplayNameAttribute` or `ToolBoxItemAttribute` with no succes. Also `DescriptionAttribute` doesn't see to work either (I was expecting the description to be added to the toolbox item tooltip)

Or is there another way to display multiple `UserControl`-s with the same name in the Visual Studio WinForms designer toolbox ?

Using Visual Studio 2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this if you add each control to a different tab in the toolbox (just right-click in the toolbox and select Add Tab. Name each after the namespace.). This is how VS supports having controls with the same names between WinForms and web apps, for example.